# Meaning of the colon (:) symbol in mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, notation, vector-analysis

I've tried to search for the meaning of the colon symbol in the context shown below and can't find an answer. I don't think "such that" makes sense in the formulation below so I'm not sure how to read it. Hoping someone here can help. Thank you.

$$\min_\Gamma\int_{D(\Gamma)}\frac{1}2\nabla y:\nabla y \space dx$$

[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1woC.png)

Comment: Where did the image come from?  What neighboring topics are being discussed?  Context is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The image is from this paper https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/pamm.202100261 on flow optimization.

Comment: It has to do with [heat and enenrgy](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4091459/949989). That colon can only be yet another version of the dot product of vectors. Here the two gradients.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think it's another symbol for [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product). In the paper $y$ is a vector so $\nabla y$ s a square matrix, so in [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) $\nabla y:\nabla y=\partial_iy_j\partial_iy_j$.